# Java net SocketTimeoutException in Karate

Tags: karate

There are two scenarios in a single feature file, scenario 1 executes without any issues but getting the below error while executing scenario 2

```
ERROR com.intuit.karate - **java.net.SocketTimeoutException**: Read timed out, http call failed after 31237 milliseconds for URL: projectURL
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: javascript function call failed:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Comment: at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalFunctionCall(Script.java:1622)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.call(Script.java:1573)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.callAndUpdateConfigAndAlsoVarsIfMapReturned(Script.java:1690)
  at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.callAndUpdateConfigAndVars(StepDefs.java:582)
  at ✽.* call read('classpath:threadWait.js')(/Users/testing.feature:72)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing the timeouts: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

```
* configure readTimeout = 10000
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse, even after increasing the readtimeout , I keep getting the same error .  Same url is being accessed through soap UI without any issue

Comment: @AutomationTester please follow this process.https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - help us help you or fix any potential issue (highly unlikely since no one else seems to have this issue)

Comment: It was an environment issue on the devops side, thanks for the help