# How to set timeout for very scenario in Karate

Tags: karate

I need to set timeout for every scenario. It should wait for only 1 minute for particular scenario to get response otherwise start the next scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate only supports the concept of a timeout for HTTP calls. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398877/143475

If you need more, consider contributing code.

Comment: Then for Https url if getting timeout error how to handle it?

Comment: @AJRakesh maybe you have some connection issue. search karate answers for "proxy" https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+proxy

Comment: It was not a proxy I added * header Content-Length = 0 similar to postman and it worked

Comment: sounds like a bug in your server rakesh